# NameError after show some data

Tags: python, pandas, nameerror

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x1, x2, test_size=0.2)
d=len(X_train)


for i in range(d):
    print(x2[i])
```

I am using a dataset with 2500 data when i run this code this error is happen what is wrong with my code can you help me with that?? This show some data than the error

7.9
7.82
7.67
7.7
8.65
9.49
9.4
9.23
8.87
9.7
9.87
9.2
8.85
8.9
8.9
8.95
8.93
8.89
9.15
9.44
9.65
11.0
11.12
11.3
11.29
11.19
11.1
11.15
11.6
1160.0
11.77
12.05
12.04

### 13.25

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      6 
      7 for i in range(d):
----> 8     print(x2[i])
      9

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in **getitem**(self, key)
    599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
    603             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2475         try:
   2476             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2477                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2478         except KeyError as e1:
   2479             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
print(x2[i:i+1])
```

This will print ith row

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `d=len(X_train)` which gets the size of the training set, then using the size of the training set to print elements from the test set, which makes some values go out of bounds, instead the correct code should be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x1, x2, test_size=0.2)
d=len(x2)


for i in range(d):
print(x2[i])
```